# Как создать страницу пользователя после основного домена (например, instagram.com/user_page/) при регистрации

Tags: php, .htaccess

У меня есть сайт на php, где у каждого пользователя есть свой файл user1.php - это его страница, которая доступна по ссылке https://основной_домен.com/user1 (без хвостов). Это реализована ключами в index.php.

```
<?php
....
switch($m) {
case "home": default: 
include("modules/home.php"); //домашняя страница
include("tpl/footer.php");
break;

case "user1":  
include("modules/user1.php"); //страница user1
include("tpl/footer.php");
break;   

case "user2":  
include("modules/user2.php"); //страница user2
include("tpl/footer.php");
break;  
}
?>
```

Также, есть запись в файле  .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^home?$ index.php?m=home [L]
RewriteRule ^user1?$ index.php?m=user1 [L] 
RewriteRule ^user2?$ index.php?m=user2 [L] 

ErrorDocument 404 /page404
</IfModule>
```

ВОПРОС:  Как сделать так, чтобы при  регистрации юзера, автоматом создавались файлы user3.php и сделать соответствующие записи в файлы index.php и .htaccess.?
Может это делается вовсе не так, но я исхожу из того что у меня есть, но это делается в ручную...
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если страницы пользователей, в плане интерфейса,у всех одинаковые, то нужно сделать просто 1 файл для всех user.php и для каждого отдельного юзера выводить эту же самую страницу но со своими данными, чтоб получить данные нужно просто при переходе на страницу id юзера передавать, на пример https://основной_домен.com/user?id=1, затем этот id из в данном случае get'а достается и с помощью него из бд собираются данные для вывода

Comment: Да, но у меня основная задача это - уникальная ссылка каждого юзера. https://основной_домен.com/user1, https://основной_домен.com/user2 итд. Также, на странице интерфейс стандартный для всех, но настраиваемый каждым юзером самостоятельно...например дивы могут быть показаны или нет...

Comment: Как я  понял, под  "уникальная ссылка для каждого юзера"  вы имеете в виду, как в вк? vk.com/vasya228, vk.com/petya322 и.т.д? Если так, то "уникальную строчку" можно достать с помощью функции `parse_url();`. Насчет div'ov уточните поподробнее, т.к не ясно, что вы в виде имеете

Comment: а как использовать функцию parse_url(); пример можете показать или как то поподробнее№№№может ресурс есть какой ...   по дивам, имеется ввиду карточки у разных юэеров может отличаться...но это не главное...

Comment: Сначала нужно получить сам url,  тут на сайте  https://snipp.ru/php/url-tekuschey-stranicy есть несколько вариантов, затем к этому url и применяем функцию parse_url($url,XX) XX- второй параметр, по умолчанию стоит -1 и выводит полный url, можно поменять на пример на 1(PHP_URL_PATH) и как раз получим  весь путь до уникального имени юзера включительно

Answer (score 0):

Обычно это делается так.

В .htacess оставляется только одно правило.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ index.php?m=$1 [L]
```

Тут используется регулярное выржаение (regexp)  ".*", под которое попадают любые символы. Из-за того что это выражение взято в скобки, то его результат сохраняется в переменной $1 - которую можно использовать в данном правиле. И она используется для передачи данных в параметр m.

По сути это правило заменяет те три правила, которые у вас есть. А так же заменяет то множество правил, которые вы хотели добавить.

Т.е. любой запрос вида site.com/abcd будет преобрасован в /index.php?m=abcd

Дальше уже в вашем коде, вы можете обрабатывать полученный параметр. Если у вас все завязано на файлы, то код может быть примерно таким

```
if(isset($_GET['m'])) {
  $m = $_GET['m'];
} else {
  $m = 'home'; //если параметр не указан, то по умолчанию это home
}

$filename = 'modules/' . $m . '.php'; //формируем имя файла

//если такое файл есть, то подключаем его. 
if (file_exists($filename)) {
  include($filename);
} else {
//здесь можно либо выводить ошибку, либо подключить home как файл по умолчанию
}
include('tpl/footer.php');
```

Насчет кода не уверен, что он без ошибок. Но думаю основную идею передает. И это общая идея. А вообще тут есть несколько важных моментов. Например, надо проверять параметр **$m** чтобы в нем не передали что-то некорректное. Надо, обдумать тот вопрос насколько целесообразно использовать файлы, а не перейти например на базу данных. И т.д. и т.п.

Comment: Немного разобрался, но возник вопрос следующий:  в строке браузера передал значение $m (abcd - это логин) как  site.com/abcd. Затем в БД по данному параметру $m = $_GET['m']; строю массив как $login=protect(isset($_GET['m']) ? $_GET['m']:0); //логин пользователя
$user_info = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE 'login'='$login'");
$row_info = $user_info->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$tel = isset($row_info['tel']) ? $row_info[' tel']: 'null';    НО! из БД возвращается NULL вместо номера телефона.  ПОЧЕМУ?  Печатаю значение $login - оно как бы есть, но по нему ничего не находит в БД